# Firefox does not allow blank contenteditable area

Tags: jquery, html, css

Firefox version 30.

Following code works perfectly in chrome and I can start typing in Paragraph.

But it does not work in firefox, any clues what is wrong

```
<div>
    <div>
      <span contenteditable="false">Not editable area</span>
        <p contenteditable="true"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/30/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome seems to automatically assign some height to the contenteditable  paragraph but Firefox doesn't. Simple solution is to add min-height to the paragraph.

```
<p contenteditable="true" style="min-height:15px"></p>
```

Now we dont have to worry about extra spaces and unnecessary br tags

Answer (score 2):

CSS solution:

```
p[contenteditable] { min-height: 1em}
/* or more generic for any element*/
[contenteditable] { min-height: 1em}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L6mVP/)**</kbd>